# Problems with xlwings sheet.range(a,b)value

Tags: python, xlwings

Can someone help me with this?

```
import xlwings as xw

workbook = xw.Book(workbook)
sheet = workbook.sheets[sheet]

value = sheet.range(8, 14).value
```

I have checked that workbook and sheet were properly initiated. I expect to get the value of cell N8 which exists in this sheet and has value.
But I have the error.

```
Exception has occurred: ValueError
Invalid parameters
```

I use MAC OS

I was trying to check all the parameters, import xlwings, played with different set of parameter including

```
value = sheet.range('N8').value
```

Read again xlwings documentation
Asked chatGPT:)

Comment: This works :       value = sheet[8,14].value

Comment: Maybe a difference with MACOS, `value = sheet.range(8, 14).value` would work in Wndows and so would `value = sheet.range('N8').value`.

Comment: Try to replace `sheet = workbook.sheets[sheet]` with `sheet = workbook.sheets[0]`.